# Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome 3 is experiencing random reboots

Tags: 14.04, gnome, reboot

Ubuntu 14.04 with GNOME 3 is experiencing random reboots. I've never had any random reboot issues with Windows, so I am quite confident that it's not a hardware/heat issue.

Currently I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed running GNOME 3 with a bunch of extensions installed. I've already experienced two random reboots today without any error messages. I'm not sure how to diagnose this. Is there a way to lookup a log that shows an error message?

Specs:

- CPU: AMD Athlon X4 630 OC
- RAM: 12GB
- SSD: Crucial 256GB
- HDD: WD 640 GB
- HDD: Samsung 256GB
- GPU: ATI Radeon 7790
- PSU: OCZ 500W

Comment: The most common cause I have seen causing this is overheating. Turn your computer off and clean it out. Other causes may be a faulty kernel module, identify and list your hardware. Check your logs for errors.

Comment: Hi bodi! I don't think that's possible. Firstly, I have a fan controller, so I am constantly monitoring my temps. Secondly, I cleaned out my desktop tower about 2 weeks ago as I was installing new ram. I am pretty sure it's not a overheating issue. How do I check my logs?

Comment: If you just installed new RAM, check it is properly fitted and test it (memtest at boot)

Comment: Tested it with memtest when I first bought it without errors.

Comment: Considering that this was a recent hardware change and that you are having a problem I suggest you either test it again, or remove it and see if it resolves your problem.

Comment: I was running the new ram install on Windows 8.1 with ZERO issues for a week. I highly doubt it's hardware.

Answer (score 0):

First fix your broken packages by issuing the commands:

> sudo dpkg --purge --force-all xorg-video-abi-11 xorg-video-abi-12 xorg-video-abi-13xorg-video-abi-14 xorg-video-abi-15
>
> sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
>
> sudo apt-get install -f

Then install fglrx & xorg drivers:

> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
>
> sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates

Comment: I am getting the following error when I run that command.

"The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fglrx-updates : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                          xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                          xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                          xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                          xorg-video-abi-15
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: When I run:

"sudo dpkg --purge --force-all xorg-video-abi-11 xorg-video-abi-12 xorg-video-abi-13xorg-video-abi-14 xorg-video-abi-15"

I get this error:

"dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove xorg-video-abi-11 which isn't installed
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove xorg-video-abi-12 which isn't installed
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove xorg-video-abi-13xorg-video-abi-14 which isn't installed
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove xorg-video-abi-15 which isn't installed"